# PfSense FreeBSD on OVH Public Instance - no internet connection

Tags: networking, freebsd, pfsense

I have no internet connectivity in freshly installed PfSense system.
Steps:

1. I've created OVH instance with Ubuntu and I mounted `mfsbsd` image.
2. After booting to `mfsbsd` there was also internet problem. Couldn't download anything or ping at all.
3. I copied PfSense image through SSH using local network.
4. I installed PfSense with `UFS BIOS option`.
5. Using OVH console I can see that PfSense booted properly after restart. I configured also reverse proxy on nginx using other server in the same local network (`http://192.168.10.22/ --> https://pfsense.domain.com/`). After that I can reach GUI through `pfsense.domain.com` URL, but there's an error after logging in and I can't do anything in UI:

> An HTTP_REFERER was detected other than what is defined in System >
> Advanced (https://pfsense.domain.com/). If not needed, this check can
> be disabled in System > Advanced > Admin Access.

6. After logging in to PfSense server using console I noticed that there's also network connectivity problem.
7. Some outputs:

```
[2.5.2-RELEASE][admin@pfSense.home.arpa]/root: ifconfig
    vtnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
            options=800b8<VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,LINKSTATE>
            ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
            inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%vtnet0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
            inet 123.123.123.123 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 123.123.123.123
            media: Ethernet 10Gbase-T <full-duplex>
            status: active
            nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    vtnet1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
            options=800b8<VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,LINKSTATE>
            ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
            inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%vtnet1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2
            inet 192.168.10.22 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.10.255
            media: Ethernet 10Gbase-T <full-duplex>
            status: active
            nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    enc0: flags=0<> metric 0 mtu 1536
            groups: enc
            nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
            options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
            inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
            inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
            inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
            groups: lo
            nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    pflog0: flags=100<PROMISC> metric 0 mtu 33160
            groups: pflog
    pfsync0: flags=0<> metric 0 mtu 1500
            groups: pfsync

[2.5.2-RELEASE][admin@pfSense.home.arpa]/root: netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
123.123.123.123    link#1             UHS         lo0
123.123.123.123/32 link#1             U        vtnet0
127.0.0.1          link#4             UH          lo0
192.168.10.0/24    link#2             U        vtnet1
192.168.10.22      link#2             UHS         lo0
213.186.33.99      xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  UHS      vtnet0

Internet6:
Destination                       Gateway                       Flags     Netif Expire
::1                               link#4                        UH          lo0
fe80::%vtnet0/64                  link#1                        U        vtnet0
fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%vtnet0  link#1                        UHS         lo0
fe80::%vtnet1/64                  link#2                        U        vtnet1
fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%vtnet1  link#2                        UHS         lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                     link#4                        U           lo0
fe80::1%lo0                       link#4                        UHS         lo0

[2.5.2-RELEASE][admin@pfSense.home.arpa]/root: ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host

[2.5.2-RELEASE][admin@pfSense.home.arpa]/root: ping serverfault.com
ping: cannot resolve serverfault.com: Host name lookup failure
```

8. I checked `/etc/defaults/rc.conf` and options `defaultrouter` and `gateway_enable` were set to `NO`. I changed them to `YES`, but It didn't help after rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved:

- I created `OpenVPN` tunnel in OVH server,
- After connecting to the `OpenVPN` network I opened the `PFSense` GUI using private IP address and I was able to disable `HTTP_REFERER`. 
   *I couldn't figure it out how to disable it from cli.*
- From GUI I added OVH Gateway IP address to WAN interface and the connectivity has started working. It's under `Interface -> WAN-> IPv4 Upstream gateway`. 
  *I was trying to do the same by changing default routing in FreeBSD OS using cli, but it didn't want to work.*